# Why does Chrome open a blank tab on OS X?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

When I click a link in an application (e-mail, Twitter, Facebook), Chrome (my default browser) opens the link, but also opens a blank "New Tab" at the same time.

Can I turn this behavior off? It's very annoying, since the blank tab gets the focus and I have to close it to see the link I actually wanted.